# Tkinter python scrollbar on selection

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, interface, scrollbar

I'm trying to make a basic python interface for demo purposes and I really want to keep it simple. I have to use two scrollbars side by side. In `scrollbarNR1` there are some user numbers and the other one has to be refreshed whenever someone clicks between the users. I tried to solve it with a recursive function by refreshing every `20 milliseconds` my `scrollbarNR2` but that just doesn't work because it clears my selection. My question is, how can I tell if my scrollbar was clicked and refresh the data just then?

My code is:

```
import tkinter

F1 = tkinter.Frame()
userScroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(F1)
userList = tkinter.Listbox(F1)

userScroll.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
userList.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y)

userScroll['command'] = userList.yview
userList['yscrollcommand'] = userScroll.set

//here comes the insertion loop with the datas - irrelevant atm

def userSelect():
    selectedUser = userList.get('active')
    print(selectedUser)

    userScroll.after(20, userSelect)
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you should look into tkinter events (specifically `<<ListboxSelect>>`) and how to register callbacks for/bind to them.

Comment: Oh god thank you! I'm pretty lost in this territory, you saved me some time!